# what is the difference between android ndk r9 legacy tool chain and android ndk r9 on windows 64

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to upgrade my android ndk to r9. But in the windows option for 64 bit i see the above two options.
I can't seem to find the difference between them online
Can someone please elaborate

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Android NDK allows the use of several different compilers and linkers. The default is currently GCC 4.6, which is the only one distributed with the "android-ndk-r9" package, and which will fit the needs of most developers.

The second package, "android-ndk-r9-legacy", contains the additionnal compilers and linkers, such as Clang. It is an additional package that you merge with the "classical" android NDK if you need to use one of these compilers/linkers.

In short, except if you're planning on using a specific compiler, don't download the "legacy" package but only the "classical" one.